# iOS overlay a header cell over another cell in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom header bar in my UITableView that I want to overlap the cell below it. Does anyone know if this is possible? At the moment I've tried off setting the scroll up but doesn't seem to work does anyone have any ideas?

Here's what I have tried

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) return 200;
    else return 100;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return @"";
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hm_pullToRefreshBar.png"]];

    return headerView;
}
```

**EDIT:** I've tried to make the header height 10 pixels shorter than the UIView that I've set for the header view, but that just cuts the graphic off instead of letting it overlap.

Comment: If you want to overlap the first cell, why dont you just add a UIview with the information that overlaps the cell?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want to do? Couldnt you do it without any header view and just a plain UIview?